# Object.keys() return not working in Ant Design table column rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, antd

I'm trying to render an [Ant Design table](https://ant.design/components/table/) featuring a people column which should look like this:

> **Adults:** 2 **Children:** 3

Here's a sample `dataSource` object:

```
{
    id: 'KRO066',
    key: 'KRO066',
    date: '01/01/2020',
    people: { adults: 2, children: 3 },
    status: 'Confirmed',
    total: '563.25',
}
```

Here's the people column render function in my `column` object:

```
{
    title: 'People',
    dataIndex: 'people',
    key: 'people',
    render: people => Object.keys(people).forEach(function (type, i) {
        return <span key={i}><strong>{type}:</strong>{people[type]}</span>;
    })

}
```

The column does not return anything, instead, I get an empty cell.

What's wrong with the render function?

Comment: how is this `render` function being called? i.e. what is the argument `people` going to be?

Comment: Shouldn't the outputted value be in squiggly brackets? {people[type]}

Comment: do you perhaps mean to use `Object.keys(people).map` rather than `Object.keys(people).forEach`?

Comment: @martinedwards It should and I fixed it but I still don't get anything returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys(people).map` instead of `Object.keys(people).forEach`

Credit @Hamms in the question comments

Comment: map return an array..
Foreach doesn't.. 
So foreach doesn't work